# Build a C++ project with OpenCV 4.5.x in Visual Studio with custom flags for ffmpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

Our C++ project in MS Visual Studio under Windows 10 uses OpenCV 4.5.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
```

The project works well. The OpenCV uses ffmpeg as dependency for extracting video frames from a stream or a file. Our legals require following flags **are not used** when compiling the ffmpeg to approve the product release:

- without `--enable-gpl`
- without `--enable-nonfree`

So far [this page](https://newbedev.com/configure-and-build-opencv-to-custom-ffmpeg-install) gets close to the answer, however, I cannot understand how to configure the Visual Studio to use custom flags just for ffmpeg and not for other dependencies. Elaboration is appreciated.

The Visual Studio has challenging and pretty confusing (for me in person, often) menues and settings. This is the root of the question:

How/where in Visual Studio can I see which flags are used for compiling of dependent libraries?
Specifically, how can I check which flags are used in OpenCV to build the ffmpeg?

Comment: Are you using CMake or MSVS project each project  as the answers will be different for each build system ?

Comment: Hi Richard, I think we use MSVS. Why do I think so? 1. The "command line" for debug looks like: `/JMC /permissive- /Yu"pch.h" /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"c:\opencv\build\include" /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" ...` 2. in Options -> Cmake the checkbox "Prefer using Cmake" is off (deasserted). Or I am lost again in the menues...